# Not able to implement Unity framework for MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am using Unity framework for implementing Dependency Injection in my MVC project. I am using the following package from Nuget

Unity: 4.0.1

Unity.Mvc: 4.0.1

I have a interface and a class like this

```
public interface ILienholder
{
    void getThis();
    void getThat();
}

public class Lienholder : ILienholder
{
    public void getThat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("get that");
    }

    public void getThis()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("get that");
    }
}
```

I have registerd the interface and class in my UnityConfig file like this

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<ILienholder, Lienholder>();
}
```

and registered it in the Global.asax file like this

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    UnityWebActivator.Start();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

I have implemented Dependency Injection in my controller like this

```
public class InsuranceVerificationPortalController : Controller
{
    public ILienholder LienholderBusinessService { get; set; }
    public InsuranceVerificationPortalController(ILienholder LienholderBusinessService)
    {
        this.LienholderBusinessService = LienholderBusinessService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.LienholderBusinessService.GetCoverage(new List<PolicyVinRequest>());
        return View();
    }
}
```

but when I run my mvc appplicaiton I get the following error like this
is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

What am I doing wrong, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: @Koopakiller do you know how to solve the problem which i am facing?

Comment: Based on the posted code everything looks good.  Can you also post `UnityMvcActivator.cs` (which contains the `UnityWebActivator` class)?